# Building a generalized notification system: passive vs. active

Tags: design-patterns, web-development, relational-database

Recently, I've tried my hand at building a notification system, but I quickly found that notifications are tricky things, especially in the context of building a general model. The diversity of what triggers them (from a clicking a button to something timing out; "actions" as I will call them), who is to be notified, and even what kind of message to send mandates an extremely flexible system to define and manage them.

I've seen many solutions advocating for an "active" approach, where the events that spawn notifications themselves create them. However, in my mind, this is the equivalent of a faulty toaster telling emergency services that it started a fire.

The metaphor applies both in terms of active intervention on the part of the actor, which decentralizes notifications (wait, which parts of the code create notifications again, and when do these happen?), as well as muddying the responsibilities of parts of the overall system, giving a lot of power to the actions which should focus on, well, acting.

On the other hand, it is completely intractable to analyse every side effects of every action, and decide what notification to spawn. Furthermore, the relationship isn't necessarily one-to-one: actions could conceivably spawn multiple notifications of varying types, destined to multiple users.

However, persistent state modification — in most cases, a database, and in mine, MySQL — is the crux of many of these actions, and I've tried to leverage this to create a notification system that can be both passive and general. The gist is as follows:

1. All actions inherit from an `Action` class that serves solely to package the "acting" part and trigger the processing of notifications.
2. During the execution of the action, all database queries are recorded.
3. After the execution has ended, the notifications, each of which list their dependencies in the database (what values changed *could* cause them to spawn), are first filtered with a boolean expression specific to the notification on the list of tables/columns that have changed.
4. The set of notifications coming out of initial filtering then query the database and each determine if they should be issued.

In case the definition of "action" extends beyond what is conveniently packageable, step 3 could execute at the end of the entire program execution, and all queries could be logged — the feasibility of which is determinable on a case-per-case basis.

The system is in the process of being fully implemented for testing in my project. However, I am concerned that relying solely on parsed queries is a rather Bad Idea. Notably, the initial filtering assumes to some extent that the queries are predictable up to the specificity of the notifications' dependencies (even if these are only specific up to tables changed, triggers pose a problem). 100% accuracy is a top priority, but at the same time, the efficiency of the system is paramount as well, especially if there is a prohibitive number of notification definitions.

Is my concern well-founded? Does there exist a [more] reliable way to achieve what I have outlined?

Comment: So if an action, e.g. `BuyProduct` fires an event `OnProductBought` which has a listener that fires some notification (e.g. your friend has just bought a watermelon), then what exactly is this action doing more than acting? I mean the thing that knows what's happening is the action. If you want to throw this knowledge away, you'll need to do some crazy stuff to get it back - e.g. parse the executed SQL - but the SQL is still part of the action so you're not getting away from it, just complicating things. And the reliability and performance of such a system is going to be questionable at least.

Comment: I really feel that you're generalising a wrong part of the system. All you'll get is a loop running through all the notifications and have them have a go on some weakly-typed info about what has probably happened. Most of the logic will still need to reside in the actions (business layer ties) and notifications (deciding whether they should fire). Also note that this creates a hidden tight coupling between actions and notifications so refactoring is not going to be pleasant either.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek You raise good points, but I'm not sure I'm totally sold. If actions and notifications are not one-to-one, then naturally many actions will issue the same notification. Assuming some Notification class structure exists for this, don't we create a tight binding, but this time from many actions to a very specific Notification subclass? This is in contrast, as I understand it, to only specific notification definitions relying on the implementation of the Actions.

Comment: The listeners in your events-based system will naturally to contain some logic on whether or not to fire a notification (lest it be a glorified notification packager). What information will they get from the Action to make this decision? I feel as though this is just another manifestation of the weak-info problem you raise.

Comment: _Assuming some Notification class structure exists for this, don't we create a tight binding, but this time from many actions to a very specific Notification subclass?_ Assume the event has any number of listeners which can be acquired through IoC (e.g. they implement `IEventListener<TEvent>` interface). Also, an action can have multiple events on it. I don't see any tihght coupling between the action and the listener.

Comment: Then there is a dependency on a concrete `TEvent` implementation which is in turn dependent on the business logic of the application in order to provide any strongly typed info to the listeners (e.g. `OnProductBought` event has args that contain the product bought, count, who bought it, ...) and the listener can do DB queries for more business data (e.g. get friends of the buyer to notify them). Therefore this idea is dependent on business logic and cannot be generalized.

Comment: Your idea is to generalize with a loss of information. That might not be a bad idea to begin with - compare e.g. C++ RAII (faulty toaster calling emergency) with garbage collection (emergency checking the toaster now and then). So in the end, it comes to the value of the outcomes. In your case the need to somehow recollect what the action has done - quite hard imo - while providing a more general approach to setting up notification dependencies. I'd still recommend you doing a proof of concept and see how it scales. I'm sceptical about that but it might work out with good tests etc.